# Why does single `=` work in `if` statement?

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

This code is provided as an example in for use with devise and OmniAuth, it works in [my project](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know why it's a single equals sign as apposed to a double equals sign, which I thought was necessary for `if`-statements. My IDE "intelliJ IDEA" agrees with my concerns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only necessary thing for an `if` statement to be valid is a boolean expression.  In this case, since `=` returns the result of the assignment, what's actually being tested is the falsiness of `session["devise.facebook_data"]`.

IntelliJ has a good point to lodge a complaint about code like this, as it's difficult to read without knowing a thing or two about Ruby.  A recommendation would be to move that to an explicit assignment statement instead.  This has the added benefit of DRYing up a reference to it twice.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      data = session["devise.facebook_data"]
      if data && data["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!! Makes sense now, you explained that perfectly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "necessary thing ... to be valid is a boolean expression." Any object can appear after `if`. Is there any "non-boolean" object that you have in mind that would make an `if` condition illegal?

Comment: @sawa When I'm near a machine I can revise that part.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, a single equals sign is used for *assignment*. The expression

```
data = session["devise.facebook_data"]
```

assigns the result of evaluating `session["devise.facebook_data"]` to a local variable named `data`.

If the `session` hash doesn't have a `"devise.facebook_data"` key, it will return `nil` and `data` will be assigned `nil`. Assignments evaluate to the value being assigned, so the assignment will evaluate to `nil` as well. `nil` is considered falsey in a boolean context, so the right operand of the `&&` will not be evaluated. That way, you won't get a `NoMethodError` trying to call `nil["extra"]["raw_info"]`.

If the `session` hash *does* have a `"devise.facebook_data"` key, `data` will be set to the value associated with it. Any value other than `nil` and `false` is considered truthy, therefore the right-hand operand of the `&&` operator will be evaluated.

If the condition is truthy, the `then` clause will be evaluated, which uses the `data` variable assigned in the condition.

---

Note: I believe one could also use the `data` variable within the right-hand side of the `&&` operator, i.e. the condition could read like this instead:

```
if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && data["extra"]["raw_info"]
```

But I'll have to check that.

Comment: Yea thats what i thought, I guess im just confused by the layout of the function.  Could you possibly explain what exactly the if is asking? I see the &&, but it seems like theres more than that?

Comment: The first `if` is equivalent to `data = ...` followed by `if data; user.email = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

A assignment operator (`=`) returns the assigned value, which is then evaluated by the `if`. In ruby, only `false` and `nil` are considered as `false`. Everything else evaluates to `true` in a boolean context (like an `if`).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby doesn't care about types in conditionals, unlike Java. As long as the value is neither nil or false then it will pass.

In your example you actually discriminate against nil: the if conditionnal ensures that data actually exists and isn't nil, so we can use it, assuming it's a hash. This is a common pattern in Ruby.

Comment: Actually, whether or not a value is falesy or not **is determined by its type (class)**, i.e., if it is an instance of `NilClass` or `FalseClass`, then it is falesy.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby returns the value when an assignment is made:

```
foo = data = 'Chalupa'
puts "foo value #{foo}"
foo value Chalupa
```

this can be used as a "trick" to verify that some code is executed only when the assignment was successful because you can use the new variable inside the if "block":

```
if klass = Object.const_get('String') rescue nil
   puts "The class indeed exists: #{klass.class}"
end
```

but as mentioned, this approach is not recommended since it's hard to read and likely Ruby has more robust and standard ways to be sure a truthy variable is in fact there, like a simple Guard Clause.